# How do I make the statusline selectable in gvim/macvim?

Tags: vimrc, gvim, macvim

With terminal vim I can just double click the statusline and select the filename, which is very handy.

In gvim or macvim clicking the statusline prompts me to resize the active window, not very useful. Is there an option to make the statusline selectable ?

Comment: If you want the filename, use `%` or the `@%` register

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'option' in gvim that lets you do it.

If you select it to copy to clipboard, then you can do:

1. `:let @*=@%` current buffer filename would be in clipboard.
2. `:let @*=expand("%:p")` current buffer full path filename would be in clipboard.
3. `:let @*=expand("%:t")` current buffer filename without path would be in clipboard.

See `:h expand()`, `:h registers`, `:h quote_%`, `:h @r`